# Is it possible using Spring Boot actuator with Jetty?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to add the Spring Boot actuator on an existing project using Jetty, and I was wondering if it's possible at all, because despite adding the library to the project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And enabling those endpoints in the application properties:

```
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
endpoints.health.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=false 
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

And even forcing the endpoints to one specific port:

```
management.server.port=9001
```

There's no way I can reach them.

I can definitely see that the endpoints are mapped though:

`[2022-10-26 15:00:37]` `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping INFO : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal) (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:543)`

The question is, where they have been mapped, cause I tried every port, and I can't find those endpoints.
[image]

Comment: If you are using Jetty as an embedded container it should work out-of-the-box. If you are deploying to an external Jetty the `management.server.port` won't do anything. Also please specify **which version** of Spring Boot you are using.

Comment: I presume you're prefixing all your requests to those endpoints with `/actuator/` right? Otherwise, you're not hitting the correct urls

Comment: @user3275784 yes, I am prefixing all the requests with /actuator/health etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using Spring Boot 1.5.10

Comment: @WebStormer When you say "There's no way I can reach them", how are you trying to reach them? What is the error that you see? Besides, is there any reason why you are using 1.5.10 version? 1.x is already out of support in around end of 2019. If you can post you full pom.xml content will be much helpful.

Comment: @AnishPanthi I can't change the spring boot version as I am working on a customer project. I try to reach the endpoint with a simple get request that always returns a 404 error

Comment: If you are trying to run in your local, you should first check on `http://localhost:<port>/<context-path>/actuator/health` and see if it is exposed in project's default context-path and port.